# Purpose of stubAllExternalIntents() in Espresso intents testing

Tags: android, testing, android-intent, android-espresso, android-testing

Looking at the following method in Google [sample for intents](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/ui/espresso/IntentsBasicSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/espresso/BasicSample/DialerActivityTest.java):

```
@Before
public void stubAllExternalIntents() {
    // By default Espresso Intents does not stub any Intents. Stubbing needs to be setup before
    // every test run. In this case all external Intents will be blocked.
    intending(not(isInternal())).respondWith(new ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null));
}
```

I see that all external intents will be blocked but I was wondering what purpose does this method serve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to perform hermetic testing, meaning that you are not interested in system intents, which may cause test flakiness depending on your assertions, that's why you are prohibiting intents that are not from your app (`not(isInternal())`).

Answer (score 0):

It does not block those intents but sets up these intent to be recorded and not passed to intent framework of android. Later you can check what all intents are recorded using intended() method. It can be used for internal intents as well.

Comment: The comments clearly says "In this case all external Intents will be blocked." and the code also seems to do so but you are saying "It does not block those intents..."

Can you please explain further?